# QuickSort OutOfBounds error

Tags: java, recursion, quicksort

I am trying to build a quickSort function that uses the median of three values as the pivot, and I am running into problems. I am running into out of bounds errors at line 56, 66, 35, 34, and 84, and am trying to change this with no avail. Any thoughts?

```
public class MyQuickSort {

    private int array[];
    private int length;

    public void sort(int[] inputArr) {

        if (inputArr.length == 0) {
            return;
        }
        this.array = inputArr;
        length = inputArr.length;
        quickSort(0, length - 1);
    }

    private void quickSort(int lowerIndex, int higherIndex) {

        int i = lowerIndex;
        int j = higherIndex;
        // calculate pivot number, I am taking pivot as middle index number
        int mid = array[(higherIndex-1)/2];
        // Divide into two arrays

        int pivot = findMedian(array, i, mid, j);
        swap(pivot, 0);

        while (i <= j) {
            /**
             * In each iteration, we will identify a number from left side which
             * is greater then the pivot value, and also we will identify a number
             * from right side which is less then the pivot value. Once the search
             * is done, then we exchange both numbers.
             */
            while (array[i] < mid) {
                i++;
            }
            while (array[j] > mid) {
                j--;
            }
            if (i <= j) {
                swap(i, j);
                //move index to next position on both sides
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }
        // call quickSort() method recursively
        if (lowerIndex < j)
            quickSort(lowerIndex, j);
        if (i < higherIndex)
            quickSort(i, higherIndex);
    }

    public static int findMedian (int[] array, int a, int b, int c) {
        if ((array[a] > array[b] && array[a] < array[c]) || (array[a] > array[c] && array[a] < array[b])) {
            return a; 
        } else if ((array[b] > array[a] && array[b] < array[c]) || (array[b] > array[c] && array[b] < array[a])) {
            return b; 
        }
        return c; 
    }


    private void swap(int i, int j) {
        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }

    public static void main(String a[]){

        MyQuickSort sorter = new MyQuickSort();
        int[] input = {24,2,45,20,56,75,2,56,99,53,12};
        sorter.sort(input);
        for(int i:input){
            System.out.print(i);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code does not have line numbers, please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36994900/edit) your question and add comments in your code where the errors occur.

Comment: how can we identify the line number of your code. atleast you should mention the line number @Thomas

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the variable "mid" is used as both an index, and a value.
The function findMedian() only expects indexes, not values in the array.

If I change the quick sort() to (note that this also includes an index bounds check for midIndex):

```
    private void quickSort(int lowerIndex, int higherIndex) {

        int i = lowerIndex;
        int j = higherIndex;
        // calculate pivot number, I am taking pivot as middle index number
        int midIndex = (higherIndex-1)/2;
        if (midIndex < lowerIndex) {
          midIndex = lowerIndex;
        }
        int mid = array[midIndex];
        // Divide into two arrays

        int pivot = findMedian(array, i, midIndex, j);
        swap(pivot, i);

        while (i <= j) {
            /**
             * In each iteration, we will identify a number from left side which
             * is greater then the pivot value, and also we will identify a number
             * from right side which is less then the pivot value. Once the search
             * is done, then we exchange both numbers.
             */
            while (array[i] < mid) {
                i++;
            }
            while (array[j] > mid) {
                j--;
            }
            if (i <= j) {
                swap(i, j);
                //move index to next position on both sides
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }
        // call quickSort() method recursively
        if (lowerIndex < j)
            quickSort(lowerIndex, j);
        if (i < higherIndex)
            quickSort(i, higherIndex);
    }
```

I get:

```
java MyQuickSort
2 2 12 20 24 45 53 56 56 75 99
```